# What's the equivalent of "add or remove programs" in Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, windows, uninstall

I wanted to install the plugin TeXlipse ([installation instructions](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/manual/installation.html)) and for that I am supposed to remove any previous version of it. Maybe the eclipse GUI is sufficient to achieve this end.

What's the equivalent of "add or remove programs" in Ubuntu?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: The original text of your question still exists [here](http://askubuntu.com/revisions/8f12eb5f-d1b1-47a8-8fdd-8306d5474e19/view-source) if you'd like to use it to ask another question.

Comment: @JacobJohanEdwards Thanks for saving the original question! I will split it up and ask separate questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Ubuntu Software Center is the equivalent of Add/Remove programs. It contains a software catalog that you add software to your system, but it can also be used to remove software.

Start the Ubuntu Software Center (it's on the Unity bar) and click on Installed at the top. Find the software application either by clicking on the appropriate category or by using the search area at the top of the window. Click on the application and then click remove on the right hand side.

Answer (score 4):

The analogue to Add/Remove porgrams in Ubuntu is USC - Ubuntu software center, which You can start from Your "main Ubuntu" menu. Which is dash in 12.04 and Gnome panel in previous versions. Also in previous versions there was Synaptic package manager, which was something like install/remove utilities and libraries from windows.

Also there is apt (Advanced Package ... something :p) which is very advanced command-line tool for installing applications and other software. (In previous versions also aptitude and dpkg are present)

So if You need to uninstall some package or app, that You know by name, try:

```
sudo apt-get remove packagename
```

or try to find it in Ubuntu Software Center, and click uninstall.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the Add/Remove applications that was *replaced* by `software-center` (`gnome-app-install`), you can't get it on the newer versions, however the closest to that would be `gnome-packagekit`.